# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method' while changing column type of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change all the columns in a dataframe to float and my code is -

```
df = pd.read_csv('Consolidated_train_data.csv')
df.drop(['investment_class', 'currency', 'fund_size','category', 'parent_company',  'fund_name', 'inception_date', 'fund_id'], axis=1, inplace=True)
medianFiller = lambda x: x.fillna(x.median)
df = df.apply(medianFiller, axis=1)    
for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('float64')
```

But on executing this I get the error -

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'
```

Comment: Have you tired printing out `df[col]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
options = {}
for col in df.columns:
    options[col] = 'float64'
df = df.astype(options)
```

or directly:

```
df = df.astype('float64')
```

reference [Pandas dataframe.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

UPDATED question:

Try using the `result_type` option of [Pandas Dataframe.apply method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: I tried both of these and still getting the same error. The issue might be because of something else. I have updated the code with more details - I am reading a csv, deleting some columns(all the categorical ones), filling na values with median(I do not understand why, but replacing na values with median changes it's data type from float to object, and in the next step I am trying to revert it to float. Any idea why this is happenings?) and then changing the columns datatype to float.

Comment: @BhabaniAcharya see updated answer, maybe the apply method needs to be refined by using result_type option

Answer (score 0):

You should just have to add `()` in line 3:

```py
medianFiller = lambda x: x.fillna(x.median())
```